# Add total number of geom_point used to Legend or axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know there are many questions about this but the ones i found does not seem to do the work for me.
I have a categorical variable on X axis and continuous on Y axis.

I am trying to add the total number of points used in geom_point in the legend(or top corner of plot) and also add the one for each category under its axis label.
This is my code for ggplot with an example data:

```
ds <- data.frame(groupage = sample(c(1,2,3),2000, replace=TRUE), moneyearned = sample(20,replace = TRUE))
p<- ggplot(ds, aes(x=groupage, y=moneyearned)) +geom_point() + stat_sum() + scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:3,labels=c("67-72 yo", "73-77 yo", "78-84 yo"))
p
```

As exemple, with 2000 observations, if there are 573 in category 1, 784 in category 2, 636 in category 3 and 7 missing values, I would like the "n=2000-missings" to show in the legend(or top corner of plot), and "n=573", "n=784", "n=636" to show under their respective category label on X axis.

Any help or reference to some post I didn't find will be appreciated :)

Comment: where is your example data

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. On the x axis, do you want to annotate the number of points that are drawn? Or the number of rows in your data frame with this category (which is, in a way, the number of points that are represented by the dots that are actually drawn)? And what do you want tfor the legend? It already tells you, how many points are represented by which dot size. Isn't this what you want? What is it, then?

Comment: I edited the post to answer your question. The stat_sum() gives the amount for each circle in the plot but I would want to know how many total points there are in the plot to show aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table()` to count the data points per category. Then, you can add these numbers to a vector of x-axis labels:

```
tab <- table(ds$groupage)
x_labs <- paste0(c("67-72 yo", "73-77 yo", "78-84 yo"), " (n=", tab, ")")
```

`x_labs` is then used in `scale_x_discrete()`. The legend is actually for the size aesthetics, so you can use `labs(size = "title")` to set the title:

```
ggplot(ds, aes(x=groupage, y=moneyearned)) + 
  geom_point() + stat_sum() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:3,labels=x_labs) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(paste0("n = ", sum(tab))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) It seems to work except that the resulting plot is zoomed in and i can't see the X axis anymore :/ (using R 3.2.3 in RStudio) The problem is occuring only when i add scale_x_discrete option.

Comment: I'm using R 3.2.3 with RStudio as well  and I can't reproduce this problem. Have you tried it with a clean R session (i.e., deleted the workspace and restarted R)? When you store the image with `ggsave("plot.png")`, is it zoomed as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I don't know why it happened but now it is showing properly. There is only one thing, is is possible to exclude the missing values in the count (either missing in groupage or moneyearned) ? For the legend i changed sum(tab) for length(na.omit(moneyearned)) because there are no missing values in groupeage.  Thanks for your patience and help :)

Comment: In the end, i created a new data set `ds3 <- na.omit(subset(ds, select= c(groupage, moneyearned )))` and used this dataset for the table and legend so it excludes missing values.

Comment: Sorry, I did not manage to answer earlier. Using `subset()` the way you do is not necessary, because it does nothing. You keep all the rows and select both columns, so `subset(ds, select= c(groupage, moneyearned ))` is really the same as `ds`. Just `ds3 <- na.omit(ds)` is enough.

Comment: yeah true for my example! I used a subset because my original dataset contains about 40 variables

Comment: which means that you did a good job making your example *minimal*.